# Do these boards have a name?

Tags: word-request

[image]

The board with the word Google Cloud, does it have a name in English? I also see some of them attached on buildings, do those also have the same word? What do we call them?

Comment: I would just call it "a sign".  There might be a more specific name in the industry that makes and sells them, but I think 99% of Americans would just call it "a sign".

Comment: To be clear, you mean boards that identify the name of the building or the name of the company inside the building?

Comment: Yes, is it called a signpost? Because I was trying various terms and it seems it's the closest term I found.

Comment: @Sayaman A signpost is a post (pole) with one or more signs on it. A sign that isn't on a post is just a sign.

Comment: At least in British English, a signpost is a pole set up at a road junction with long, narrow boards at the top pointing in the directions of the different roads, with the names of the places those roads lead to. They have mostly been replaced by modern signboards with arrows showing the routes.

Answer (score 3):

You can call these a "building sign", "business sign" or "company sign".

If it's in a public place, such as a roadside, or even attached to a wall somewhere, advertising a building or business that's elsewhere, it's called a "billboard".